# How to call handle_event from test using Elixir Live View

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In LiveView how do I call a handle_event from within a test.

```
  @impl true
  def handle_event("do_thing", _, socket) do
    send(self(), :do_the_thing)
    {:noreply, assign(socket, :cycler, true)}
  end
```

Comment: What kind of event do you want to test? Is it one of the default ones? (click, submit, change, keyup, etc.)? Or is it a custom one? And what does your test currently look like?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't directly call it, but take a look at the `render_hook/3` function available with `Phoenix.LiveViewTest`.

```
{:ok, view, _html} = live(conn, "/thermo")
assert view
       |> element("#thermo-component")
       |> render_hook(:refresh, %{deg: 32}) =~ "The temp is: 32℉"
```

source: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveViewTest.html#render_hook/3